# How to compute an integral with $max$ in it?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How do you compute this integral?

$$\int_{E} z\cdot \max\{x, y\} dx dy dz$$

where $$E:=\left\{(x,y,z) \in R^3 | 0 \leq x, y \leq z \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right\} $$

I don't know what to do with $max\{x,y\}$ and $E$.

Answer (score 2):

Divide E into two pieces - one where $x>y$ and the other where $y>x$.  Then integrate $zx$ over one piece and $zy$ over the other piece.

Comment: I don't know how to divide E, but $\int zx$ $dxdydz$ would be $\frac{z^2*x^2*y}{4}$?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: the maximum of two real numbers can be written as

$$\max\{x,y\}=\frac{x+y+|x-y|}2$$